# Adding new event to office365 calendar

Tags: api, office365

I'd like to add new events to custom calendar (named "Calendar XY") using **Office 365 API**. I don't know why, but all events are always added into default calendar (named "Calendar").

`_client.Me.Calendars[myCalendar.Id].Events.AddEventAsync(newEvent);`

When inspecting using Fiddler I've noticited, that even when `@odata.context` was correct (with Id of "Calendar XY"), `@odata.editLink` still pointed to default calendar ID.

Here it is complete context, but I don't see there anything interesting:

```
        const string ExchangeResourceId = "https://outlook.office365.com";
        const string ExchangeServiceRoot = "https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata";

        var _authenticator = new Authenticator();
        var authInfo = await _authenticator.AuthenticateAsync(ExchangeResourceId);
        var _client = new ExchangeClient(new Uri(ExchangeServiceRoot), authInfo.GetAccessToken);

        var myCalendar = await (
            from calendar in _client.Me.Calendars
            where calendar.Name == "Calendar XY"
            select calendar
            )
            .ExecuteSingleAsync();

        var newEvent = new Event
        {
            Start = dayData.DateTimeFrom,
            End = dayData.DateTimeTo,
            Location = new Location { DisplayName = dayData.Location },
            Subject = dayData.Subject,

            Importance = Importance.Low,
            ResponseRequested = false,
            ShowAs = FreeBusyStatus.Free,
        };

        await _client.Me.Calendars[myCalendar.Id].Events.AddEventAsync(newEvent);
```

Comment: You just show one line of code, can you show the complete code for adding the event?

Comment: check my original post (I've added a deeper context)

Answer (score 1):

First off, thank you for using the new Office 365 APIs!  After digging into this, it appears as if this is a bug that is at the service layer.  I opened up a tracking issue.  We will need to dig into this and do some code changes on our side.  We will be addressing this issue, however I don’t have an ETA as to when it will be fixed in the service.  Thanks for the feedback!

David Los
Senior Program Manager - Exchange

Comment: Hi David, thanks for feedback. Can you please notify me, that it's done, when It gets done?